# NullReferenceException in unittesting with NUnit, NSubstitute, and async method

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, async-await, nunit, nsubstitute

I'm doing some unit testing in C# using NUnit and NSubstitute. I have a class called `Adapter`, which has a method, `GetTemplates()`, I want to unit test. `GetTemplates()` uses `httpclient`, which I have mocked out using an interface.

The call in `GetTemplates` looks something like:

```
public async Task<List<Template>> GetTemplates()
{
    //Code left out for simplificity. 

    var response = await _client.GetAsync($"GetTemplates");

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    { 
        throw new Exception();
    }

}
```

I want `_client.GetAsync` to return a `HttpResponseMessage` with a `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest` so that I can test if the exception is being thrown.

The test method looks like:

```
[Test]
public void GetTemplate_ReturnBadRequestHttpMessage_ThrowException()
{
     //Arrange.
     var httpMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     _client.GetAsync("").Returns(Task.FromResult(httpMessage));

     //Act.
     var ex = Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await _Adapter.GetSigningTemplates());

     //Assert.
     Assert.IsInstanceOf<Exception>(ex);
 }
```

When the method has run, it returns

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the arrangement of the mocked client does not match what is actually invoked when the test is exercised.

The client expects

```
var response = await _client.GetAsync($"GetTemplates");
```

but the setup is for

```
 _client.GetAsync("")
```

note the different arguments passed. When mocks do not get exactly what was setup they usually return the default value of their return type, which in this case is *null*.

Change the test to use the expected parameter

```
_client.GetAsync($"GetTemplates").Returns(Task.FromResult(httpMessage));
```

Reference [Return for specific args](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-for-args/)

or use an argument matcher

```
_client.GetAsync(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(Task.FromResult(httpMessage));
```

Reference [Argument matchers](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/)

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I also realized that I had a wrong order in the constructor.